# Content disappears under fixed element when fixed element stays on top when scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a problem with some content, which disappears under the fixed element when page is being scrolled down. The JS fiddle below shows it very well.
Basically the content above number 7 jumps behind the fixed navigation element. I assume there must be a simple {padding-top:100px;} applied for body through js after sticking the header on top.

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/a3fm7k1g/)

```
<div id="ontop">something</div>
<header>navigation - stays on top when scrolling</header>
<div id="wrapper"> 
    1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>
    7 - wrapper disappears above this point while scrolling down<br/> 
    8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ontop {width:100%; height:80px; background-color:yellow;}
header {width:100%; height:100px; background-color:lightgrey;}
#wrapper {background-color:lightblue; height:5000px;}

.navfixed {position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width:100%; display:block; margin-bottom:120px;}
```

and finally JS:

```
$(function () {
    var elem = $('aside'),
        elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        elem.toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    }).scroll();
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to add a `padding-top` when the navbar becomes fixed?

Comment: do you want to show `#top` also on scroll or just `#wrapper`?

Comment: @ankitchaudhary thanks, you sorted this well. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @JoelAlmeida it's sorted by Ankit below. I mentioned that I need that padding applied "after sticking the header on top", so after the navbar becomes fixed, yes. All sorted. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to set top margin to `#wrapper` element toggling `wrapperBelow` class on scroll

```js
$(function () {
    var elem = $('header'),
        wrapperElem = $('#wrapper'),
        elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        elem.toggleClass('navfixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
         wrapperElem.toggleClass('wrapperBelow', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    }).scroll();
});
```

```css
#ontop {width:100%; height:80px; background-color:yellow;}
header {width:100%; height:100px; background-color:lightgrey;}
#wrapper {background-color:lightblue; height:5000px;}

.navfixed {position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width:100%; display:block; margin-bottom:120px;} 
.wrapperBelow{
    margin-top:112px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ontop">something</div>
<header>navigation - stays on top when scrolling</header>
<div id="wrapper"> 
    1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>
    7 - wrapper disappears before this while scrolling<br/> 
    8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
</div>
```